# Invalid ROM Contents preventing boot on MacBook

Tags: boot, macbook-pro, refit

I'm booting Ubuntu from rEFInd on a 15" MacBook Pro.  For a long time I haven't had a problem, but just now booting has been hanging on the error

> Invalid ROM Contents

This seems to happen when it attempts to mount `/dev/sda3` which is the Ubuntu partition.  I've read that this may be related to graphics and I can boot an older version of the Kernel without graphics, however nothing else that I have read has helped and I am at a loss as to what to do.  Any suggestions for fixing this error?

Comment: You might need to find a patch for the graphics of your Mac. From what it sounds like, it might be related to a problem solved [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=138901). See if that can fix your problem, but if it's not related, someone else or myself will get back to you with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the nvidia drivers seems to have fixed the problem.  Boot headless (you can probably use one of the backup kernels).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-310
```